# How to use the Pytrends API in countries other than US

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I would like to get top charts in Switzerland for the past years. First, I try with the examples given for the US to test the code.

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
top = pytrends.top_charts('201801', 'actors', geo='US', cat='')
```

and that works. If I look at the URL, it looks like `https://trends.google.com/trends/topcharts#vm=trendingchart&cid=actors&geo=US&date=201801&cat=` so this is making a lot of sense.

Next, I would like to get the top charts for Switzerland (CH). I go to [google trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/topcharts#geo=CH&date=2017) and select Switzerland, I realize that the date field is only year (e.g. `2017`), not year and month as for the US (e.g. `201701`). I also realize that the categories are in German (I live in Switzerland and I'm not using any proxy). And the URL looks different as in the US: `https://trends.google.com/trends/topcharts#vm=trendingchart&cid=cc6d37e9-0573-4579-a813-3c18cd6da621&geo=CH&date=2017&cat=`

So I set the parameters as follows:
 1. `cid='cc6d37e9-0573-4579-a813-3c18cd6da621'`, because I believe it's how Google deals with categories in other languages, such as 'Städte & Dörfer' (cities and towns).
 2.  `geo='CH'`
 3.  I'm not sure exactly on how to set the handle parameters so I use `hl='de-CH'` where `de` is german and `CH` is Switzerland and `tz=48`.

Then, I try to run:

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='de-CH', tz=48)
top = pytrends.top_charts('2018', 'cc6d37e9-0573-4579-a813-3c18cd6da621', geo='CH', cat='')
```

and also:

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
top = pytrends.top_charts('2018', 'cc6d37e9-0573-4579-a813-3c18cd6da621', geo='CH', cat='')
```

Both of which do not work and output the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jguedes/trends/get_trends.py", line 6, in <module>
top = pytrends.top_charts('2018', 'cc6d37e9-0573-4579-a813-3c18cd6da621', geo='CH', cat='')
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytrends/request.py", line 344, in top_charts
params=chart_payload,
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytrends/request.py", line 101, in _get_data
'response with code {0}.'.format(response.status_code), response=response)
pytrends.exceptions.ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 404.
```

Does anyone know how to get the top charts by year in Switzerland or other countries?

Comment: Your misunderstood the meaning of `cid=`. Read [top-charts](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends#top-charts)

Comment: I didn't. What would you say is the `cid` for 'Städte & Dörfer' ?

Comment: Referring to [google-language-codes](https://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-language-codes), there is no `hl=de-CH`.

Comment: those are categories, different from `cid`... for the US one can choose categories as well as main topic (`cid`) but this is not possible in CH. Tha'ts why the `cat` parameter is empty.

Comment: regarding the language, `en-US` is not on that list but it works nonetheless. In any case, changing language to `de` doesn't work either...

Comment: My bad, your are right: `cat` **is not** `cid`